# Are there any rules as to how IP address should be assigned to each container in OpenVZ?

Tags: ip, openvz

I have OpenVZ running on CentOS system connected to a LAN.The internal IP address of the host machine is 192.168.2.152.Two containers have been created and the IP addresses I assigned are 
192.168.0.101 and 192.168.0.102.Is this valid?

Answer (score 0):

The IPs are valid. You haven't stated if thy're configured on a venet or veth device, which might mean you need to do additional configuration though.

Comment: They are configured on a venet device.